# Price with no points or commas

Tags: magento-1.9

I need to test a payment gateway and the sandbox only accept prices with no points or commas on it. Is there a simple way to change it on magento?

Thanks!

Comment: You could try to map another field just to test. After that you will want to filter before the API.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a simple way, the best way is to filter before sending them to gateway.